# Could anyone review our extension for donation receipts?

Tags: civicontribute, extension, contributions, receipts

We developed an extension for issuing donation receipts. Initial development was funded by seven German organizations and they just released the extension under a free license.

It can be found in the [CiviCRM Extension directory](https://civicrm.org/extensions/donation-receipts) some documentation is in the [CiviCRM Wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/DonationReceipts+Extension).

Would anyone who is eligible to do so review the extension so it can be marked for automated distribution? Obviously everyone is also very welcome to test the extension's functions and provide feedback ^__^

Thanks!

Comment: If you want automated distribution you should setup your github to use releases and then each new release on github is automaticly added as a release on the CiviCRM extension page

Answer (score 1):

Awesome

Did you look at the extension from Karin? Do you know how it compares?
https://civicrm.org/extensions/cdn-tax-receipts

Comment: Yes, we considered tweeking the one of Karin (as well as another one) before we started. However, due to some rather specific requirements of the customers, we decided against it and started fresh.